# how to install file packages in magento 1.5

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm using magento 1.5. I have a requirement to install a third-party ecommerce package. When i log into Magento Connect, i do not see "Direct package file upload" as an option.

In 1.5 how do i upload a zip/tgz etc?

[image]

Comment: why do you think it should be there?

Comment: well the above is in the docs from my third party package. How do you install a package from a zip? Or should i go back to them and ask for a extension key. Very much a newbie to magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 1.5.1 and the "direct package file upload" appeared.

Comment: ok, but which FORMAT is accepted here? tried a zip and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why the "direct package file upload" doesn't show up (maybe a permission issue?) but you can manually upload the files/folders where they belong.
At the very least you'll have one folder to put into **app/code/community/** and one file into **app/etc/modules/**. And maybe something in app/design/frontend/base/default/, lib/ and skin/.
If you list the contain of the extension I'll be able to help you more precisely.